# SwiftUI: popover to persist (not be dismissed when tapped outside)

Tags: swiftui, popover

I created this popover:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Popover : View {
  @State var showingPopover = false

  var body: some View {

    Button(action: {
      self.showingPopover = true
    }) {
      Image(systemName: "square.stack.3d.up")
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover){

    Rectangle()

      .frame(width: 500, height: 500)

    }
  }
}

struct Popover_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Popover()
        .colorScheme(.dark)
        .previewDevice("iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)")
    }
}
```

[image]

Default behaviour is that is dismisses, once tapped outside.

Question:
How can I set the popover to:
 - Persist (not be dismissed when tapped outside)?
 - Not block screen when active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution to this problem doesn't involve spinning your own popover lookalike. Simply apply the `.interactiveDismissDisabled()` modifier to the parent content of the popover, as illustrated in the example below:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentingPopover = false
    @State private var count = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                presentingPopover.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("This view pops!")
            }.popover(isPresented: $presentingPopover) {
                Text("Surprise!")
                    .padding()
                    .interactiveDismissDisabled()
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

            Text("Count: \(count)")
            Button {
                count += 1
            } label: {
                Text("Doesn't block other buttons too!")
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Tested on iPadOS 16 (Xcode 14.1), [demo video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/64193267/201839892-050bea0d-0cb9-44a5-929a-9c80859b8cc4.mp4) included below:

[image]

*Note: Although it looks like the buttons have lost focus, they are still interact-able, and might be a bug as such behaviour doesn't exist when running on macOS.*

Answer (score 1):

I tried to play with `.popover` and `.sheet` but didn't found even close solution. `.sheet` can present you modal view, but it blocks parent view. So I can offer you to use `ZStack` and make similar behavior (for user):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Popover: View {
    
    @State var showingPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            // rectangles only for color control
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(showingPopover ? 0.75 : 1)
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showingPopover.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "square.stack.3d.up")
            }
            
            ModalView()
                .opacity(showingPopover ? 1: 0)
                .offset(y: self.showingPopover ? 0 : 3000)
        }
        
    }
}

// it can be whatever you need, but for arrow you should use Path() and draw it, for example
struct ModalView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 520, height: 520)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

struct Popover_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Popover()
        .colorScheme(.dark)
        .previewDevice("iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)")
    }
}
```

here `ModalView` pops up from below and the background makes a little darker. but you still can touch everything on your "parent" view

**update:** forget to show the result:

[image]

**P.S.**: from here you can go further. For example you can put everything into `GeometryReader` for counting `ModalView` position, add for the last `.gesture(DragGesture()...)` to offset the view under the bottom again and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! But this is working more like a modal

Answer (score -1):

You just use **.constant(showingPopover)** instead of **$showingPopover**. When you use $ it uses binding and updates your @State variable when you press outside the popover and closes your popover. If you use .constant(), it will just read the value from you @State variable, and will not close the popover.
Your code should look like this:

```
struct Popover : View {

  @State var showingPopover = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.showingPopover = true
    }) {
      Image(systemName: "square.stack.3d.up")
    }
    .popover(isPresented: .constant(showingPopover)) {
       Rectangle()
         .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
       }
    }
}
```